# How to rsync all folders present on the destination folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, rsync

I have two folders `FolderA` and `FolderB` as below. I want to `rsync` the common subfolders. For example, I can do `rsync -avzP /path/to/FolderB/* /path/to/FolderA/`, which will keep `SubFolder1` and `SubFolder3` mirrored. My question is how I can achieve the same if `FolderB` is the destination without explicitly `--include` or `--exclude` individual subfolders (e.g., in case there are too many of them).

```
FolderA
|--SubFolder1
|--SubFolder2
|--SubFolder3
|--SubFolder4

FolderB
|--SubFolder1
|--SubFolder3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update all files in `FolderA` using the ***contents*** `FolderB` as the source with your normal:

```
rsync -uav /path/to/FolderB/ /path/to/FolderA
```

(**note:** the trailing `'/'` after `FolderB/` is mandatory to copy the ***contents*** of `FolderB` rather than `FolderB` itself)

To do it in reverse and update `FolderB` from `FolderA` and not copy `SubFolder2` and `SubFolder4` with the `--existing` option which will `"skip creating new files on receiver"`, *but that will also prevent* new files and directories within `SubFolder1` and `SubFolder3` from being created as well.

You best option to not copy `SubFolder2` and `SubFolder4` while allowing new files and directories within `SubFolder1` and `SubFolder3` be created is to use the `--filter` option. See [rsync(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html).

A typical way to use `--filter` to exclude `SubFolder2` and `SubFolder4` on a copy from `FolderA` to `FolderB` would be:

```
rsync -uav --filter -_SubFolder2/ --filter -_SubFolder4/ /path/to/FolderA/ /path/to/FolderB
```

That will allow you to copy the complete contents of `/path/to/FolderA/` to `/path/to/FolderB/` without including `SubFolder2` and `SubFolder4`.

---

**Edit Per-Comment On Large Number of SubFolders**

If you have a large number of folders under `FolderA` that you do not want to sync under `FolderB`, then your other option is to create a text file holding the *absolute path* to only those `SubFolderX` under `FolderA` you want to `rsync` to `FolderB` and then use the `--no-R` and `--files-from=folderlist` options to only `rsync` the wanted SubFolders. This will eliminate having to specify a large number of `--filter` options on the command line.

For example, you can create your folderlist with:

```
find /path/to/FolderA -maxdepth 1 -type d > folderlist
```

(**note:** specify the absolute path above and `find` will produce the `folderlist` file containing absolute paths)

Now edit your `folderlist` file and remove the parent directory (e.g. `/path/to/FolderA`) and any SubFolders you don't want to sync under `FolderB`. You can now use the `folderlist` file to control which SubFolders under `FolderA` are sync'ed to `FolderB` without having to include a long list of filters on the command line. Your command line then becomes

```
rsync -uai -r --no-R --files-from=folderlist / /path/to/FolderB
```

(**note:** the `'/'` as *source* serves as a base for the paths contained in `folderlist`. You can change the `-i` option to control the level of information dumped to the screen, e.g. `-v`, etc... or remove it altogether to suppress any reporting other than errors)

(**also note:** when using `--files-from`, `-a` does not imply `-r` (recursive), so you will need to explicitly add `-r` if you need a recursive transfer)

Comment: My use case is that there are a lot of common folders to sync (`SubFolder1`, `SubFolder2`, ...) but there are also a lot of folders to skip (`SubFolder2`, `SubFolder4`, ...), so really hoping for a way without doing anything explicit. Also, wouldn't `rsync -uav /path/to/FolderB/ /path/to/FolderA` remove `SubFolder2` and `SubFolder4` under `FolderA`?

Comment: You can always create a list of subfolders to copy in a text file, 1-per line containing the *Absolute* path, e.g. `/path/to/FolderA/SubFolder1 /path/to/FolderA/SubFolder3 ...` and then call `rsync` with the `rsync -uai --no-R --files-from=thatfile / /path/to/FolderB`. That way you only have to create the folder list once and then you can avoid any exclusions in the `rsync` call itself.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet..

Comment: Will do. I do believe this is a much better solution than what I had before, but I just wanted to give the question a few more days of exposure to potentially more ideas.

Comment: No problem whatsoever. Take as long as you like. This is a pretty obscure area of `rsync` where I've had the fortune (or misfortune) of having to deal with on a number of occasions with large software projects, package manager repositories, etc.... If there is a new or another way to do it that's better -- we will both vote for it and learn something `:)` Note, you can also pull the directory list file (`thatfile` above) from the remote host. So you can populate it based on what is in `/FolderB` on the fly and reference it from the host with `FolderA`. It's in the man page too.

Comment: I was just implementing this today and it worked wonderfully. One small omission is that `-r` is needed in addition to `-a` when using `--files-from`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is one exception to `-a` implying `-r` which I have in my notes -- getting old is a bitch. Glad you got it working. `rsync` is an amazing tool (brought to you by the same people that brought you Samba and opened windows to a wider world....) Added a note at the end.